# click a button for diffrent time

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener

I've a Button for 8 CheckBoxs and i want when i click on button a piece of my code running for example case 1 in this code for showing tick on chk1 (note.done1) .and for second time when i clicked on button,my app recognize chk1 is checked and now checking chk2(note.done2) and too for 6 another CheckBoxs.

but this code is wrong because when i click on button, chk1 and chk3 and chk5 are true.also I'm trying else if and Sharedpreferences and array .

i can't use ischecked() method because i use listview with 1000(in less) item.just i can use note.done where link to checkboxs in each item .i can use array where link to each checkboxs and sqlite too!

so can anyone help me?

```
 btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            switch (G.result_s1[position]) {
                case 0: {
                    note.done1 = true;
                    note.c = Color.RED;
                    G.database_s.execSQL("UPDATE mystate SET s1='1' WHERE s_id=" + (position + 1));
                    G.result_s1[position] = 1;
                    //AdapterNote.img.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
                    break;

                case 1:

                {
                    note.done2 = true;
                    note.c = Color.GREEN;
                    G.database_s.execSQL("UPDATE mystate SET s2='1' WHERE s_id=" + (position + 1));
                    G.result_s2[position] = 1;

                }

                    break;

            }

            switch (G.result_s3[position]) {
                case 0: {

                    note.done3 = true;
                    note.c = Color.MAGENTA;
                    G.database_s.execSQL("UPDATE mystate SET s3='1' WHERE s_id=" + (position + 1));
                    G.result_s3[position] = 1;

                }
                    break;
                case 1: {
                    note.done4 = true;
                    note.c = Color.YELLOW;
                    G.database_s.execSQL("UPDATE mystate SET s4='1' WHERE s_id=" + (position + 1));
                    G.result_s4[position] = 1;
                }
                    break;
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ischecked()?

Whenever you click the button you check another checkbox

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
          if(!checkbox1.ischecked()){
              // check checkbox1
          }else if(checkbox1.ischecked()){
            // check checkbox2
          }else if(checkbox1.ischecked() && checkbox2.ischecked()){
            // check checkbox3
          }....
    }
 }
```

Comment: i can't use ischecked() method because i use listview with 1000 item.just i can use note.done where link to checkboxs in each item .

Comment: You can try to check in the database which is the first checkbox which state is 0.

Or you can set a global variable which has the number of clicks made to be button.